# Script/Program for Quick install & config openvpn

Tags: command-line, networking, scripts, vpn, openvpn

There is documentation about OpenVPN [*manual*](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html) install and configuration.

But let be honest, this is too much if you are in a hurry and don't want all the details right now.

Indeed, it is common sense to have a script(or program) that does all the labor in the doc instead of entering each commands manually in terminal.

"What type of install do you want?" that the kind of question that the scipt/program should ask.
Then "OpenVPN server(or client) install in progress.." or something similar.

So i ask to ubuntu's super users,to share a script/program.

Comment: Lets be honest, if you want something as brain dead as just running a script/program that will do everything needed for you, maybe Ubuntu wasn't the best choice.

Comment: Ouch,but seriously,you *can* still see what's inside a script,so it's not "brain dead".

Comment: Perhaps there are too many ways to customise the install that a catch all install script wouldn't work. You also have not mentioned any of your install requirements. What type of install do you want? (Not enough rep to comment)

Comment: Perhaps there are too many ways to customise the install that a catch all install script wouldn't work. You also have not mentioned any of your install requirements. What type of install do you want? (Not enough rep to comment)

Comment: "Not enough rep to comment",i feel you,this feature is lame and doesn't help anybody ...also please see my edit.

Comment: Yeah I know. I'll do this in a bit for you then.

Comment: @user-707, the feature does help to clean the questions clean from noise in the comment section. For the moment I've added the comment for you, Shmink, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: From @Shmink : *Perhaps there are too many ways to customise the install that a catch all install script wouldn't work. You also have not mentioned any of your install requirements. What type of install do you want?*

Comment: It's possible to ask all those info in a script/program,that's more user friendly,but i understand if you don't like it this way.

Comment: This script/program,would be helpful for the community,why do i got no answers?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use to install and activate an OpenVPN client.  It could use more documentation... but you don't want to read it anyway ☺

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo Usage: install-client POD
fi

if [ ! -r client.conf ]; then
  echo Must be run from directory with conf files
fi

apt -y install openvpn
cp client.conf /etc/openvpn
cp keys/ca.crt /etc/openvpn
cp keys/$1.key /etc/openvpn/client.key
cp keys/$1.crt /etc/openvpn/client.crt

service openvpn@client start
```

Comment: first,thanks for your answer,It's not that i don't want to read,you could still comment your script,link to documentation.

Comment: i found this [script](https://linux-scout.de/sicherheit/debian-openvpn-setup-script) ,what do you think about it?

Comment: @user-707 I know, I advocate a lot for literate programming.  The script could use documentation.  I was just needling you a bit.

Comment: @user-707 I glanced at that script you linked to.  It looks OK, but it doesn't do what I want.  In my environment, I don't want any prompts.  I want to pull everything down from a web server, install, configure, and initialize with no manual interaction.  I had to read at least some of the documentation to figure it out, and the [openvpn quick start](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#quick) was pretty short and direct.